# Management of ASP.NET User Profiles

Tags: asp.net, profile

The [Storing User Profile](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/profile/default.aspx) quickstart gives some information about managing ASP.NET user profile. In my case the administrator has to be able to change/monitor some properties with profiles. Is it posible to access and change user profile's properties in another user profile by using default SqlServerProfileProvider and how?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "another user profile" you mean the profile of a user who is not the current user:

```
ProfileCommon userProfile = Profile.GetProfile(USERNAME);
userProfile.Property = "blah";
```

Comment: Yes

Will change common profile? I need property changed for specific "another" user

Comment: I edited my post. I had the USERNAME in angle brackets, so it was invisible. This should work now.